# The number of ways an even integer can be written as the sum of two primes

Tags: analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

We all know the famous Goldbach Conjecture, namely that every even intger $>2$ is the sum of two primes. I was recently playing around with this conjecture and found out that there are MANY ways of writing an even integer as the sum of two primes.

Definition: Let $A(n)$ be the number of ways $n$ can be written as the sum of two primes, where $n$=$0$(mod $2$).

Then we have that Goldbach's conjecture is equivalent to that $A(n)$ is at least $1$.

If it isn't true, please (if possible) provide a counterexample, or some sort of triviality that comes with this statement.

So if you graph this for large enough values, one observes that $A(n)$$\geq$$\sqrt n$. But $\sqrt n$$\geq1$. So would we then have Goldbach's conjecture? In other words, is the following statement true?

Conjecture(?): If one proves $A(n)$$\geq$$\sqrt n$, this would imply $A(n)$$\geq$$1$, which is Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but surely proving $A(n)\geq\sqrt n$ is even harder than proving $A(n)\geq1$

Comment: I am gonna do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your definition of $A(n)$, Goldbach conjecture would be equivalent to
saying that every **even** number $n >2$ verifies
$$A(n) \geq 1.$$
In order to prove Goldbach conjecture, it would be sufficient to prove that for any even number larger than $2$, $A(n) \geq \sqrt{n}$ (this is because $\sqrt{n} \geq 1$ when $n$ is a positive integer).

Comment: YES. Do we have the mathematical machinery to prove something like this?

Comment: If we had, we would have done it already.